# Epson et-2550 print issue

Tags: printing, epson

I hve Dualboot win10 and Ubuntu 22.04. In windows priner and scanner work fine. But after I installed Ubuntu 22.04 it only print blank sides. In win10 it print ok. I tryed install drivers but allways the same blank sites. Do I need to go back to ubuntu 20.04 where all worked fine.

Comment: Point a browser to `http://localhost:631`, the CUPS GUI. Click the "`Admin`" tab, and add your printer there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Epson proprietary printer and scanner drivers.

You can download them from [HERE](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)